# Rules data comparison: compare node field with a group

Tags: rules, organic-groups

How to use rules to compare a field from the node with a specific [Organic Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)?

I am using rules event after saving new content of type X. Now I need to specify if in the field field_group the value is a specific group.

I am able to get the field of the node, but have no clue how to be able to compare it with a group I want.

Comment: `"compare a field from the node with a specific group"` specific group name? or group users?

Comment: the group it self, if the compare only works with the name thats good to.
Not with any users in group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok, lets assume that your group name is called "Pokemon"**

1) Under Conditions, click on Add Condition.

2) In the drop down, select TEXT COMPARISON

3) Click on the Blue Link that says (DATA SELECTORS)

4) Look for your field, if you named it "group", then look for node:field-group

then highlight it, copy and paste it under Data Selector*

7) Under Matching Text put **Pokemon**

8) click SAVE

*Note: obviously, replace Pokemon with your actual group name.*

Comment: Hey, thx for the reply (i wanted to give you a vote but still not allowed)

you answer works only thing
step 4) should be node:field-group:title
just for those that needed it to

still if anyone knows another way i would like to know it (even if it is in script or patch)
cause this is a nice temp solution but not perfect.

Comment: Hey, thx for the reply (i wanted to give you a vote but still not allowed)

you answer works only thing
step 4) should be node:field-group:title
just for those that needed it to

still if anyone knows another way i would like to know it (even if it is in script or patch)
cause this is a nice temp solution but not perfect.

if anyone changes the name or you have multi lang this could be a mess +
if you do this with NID the problem is worse since the comparison operation only has
 - contiains
 - starts with
 - end with
 - regX

and not is equal
start/end with wont do
(this should be up)

Comment: @TomVanMinsel if you want equals to, you could use `DATA COMPARISON` instead of text comparison. for DATA VALUE
you can click on `switch to direct input mode` and then put your number on the field.

Comment: but then its not allowed to put a custom value
and i cant select a group either

Comment: @TomVanMinsel for custom value, you need to click on the **`switch to direct input mode`** button. **(it's a small grey button)**.

Comment: I bet this is about D7 ...